# For what reasons do manga get banned?

Tags: manga-production

Thanks to the question [Is there a list of banned manga artist whose work are not translated into English](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/is-there-a-list-of-banned-manga-artist-whose-work-are-not-translated-into-englis), which now is deleted. I was wondering, what are the reasons for manga to be banned? and does the same ruling apply to doujinshi?

I would assume there is a general rule set that is applied upon works after release, which determines if it should be banned, or at least some sort of measure to weigh it by.

Comment: Censorship mostly, particularly in controversial and/or taboo topics. Like with [Kodomo no Jikan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodomo_no_Jikan#Controversy).

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad, but perhaps that's only me. Searching for "banned manga/anime" returns many results with too many reasons (like, [Death Note is banned in China because "*teachers being scared of kids turning their own notebooks into "Death Notes."*"](https://myanimelist.net/featured/1526/10_Anime_Banned_Around_the_World)?) , which I'm not sure can be summarized.

Comment: If you specified an anime or manga then this would be much less broad.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade It probably would be, but that would not cover the question i was asking. I attempted to rephrase the original question to imply what I wanted to know a bit more. Think it would be less broad this way as well

Comment: lot of manga got banned for many different reasons in many country. Some even for ridiculous reasons. You want to cover all of that? Too broad, sadly. But most reason would be too vulgar, too violence, or offensive for some.

Comment: if it's only banned in Japan probably not as broad. Can't imagine those reasons used to banned a manga

Comment: look guys I know it seems too broad in a sense that it could potentially attract a hundred different answers, but given that in *3 years* it's got 0 answers, would it really harm the site to have this question open? And please if you have any examples of banned manga with sources citing reasons, maybe post a community wiki answer and let's all add what we find to it.